# How to say "and here I thought"

Tags: word-choice

How would I say "and here I thought you didn't understand sarcasm"? I was also wondering if there is any difference between using 皮肉 and 風刺 for meaning sarcasm.

Comment: "And here I thought X" is a bit of an idiomatic expression in English that essentially just means "I thought X" with a sense of bafflement. With that scope in mind, be prepared to receive answers that don't translate directly to "and here I thought" because translating idiomatic expressions between two unrelated languages verbatim doesn't work out well a good amount of the time.

Comment: @psosuna I understand that. I'd be satisfied with an approximate translation that conveys the same general meaning.